# Azure Hybrid Connection Manager fails to install

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008-r2

I have successfully setup a Hybrid Connection through the Azure Portal for my application and downloaded the .msi file required for the 'on-premises hybrid connection'.

However, when installing the file on the relevant 2008 R2 server (following the installation guidelines found here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/) I am getting the following errors during the install:

> Product: HybridConnectionManager 0.6.3 -- Installation failed.
>
> Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: HybridConnectionManager 0.6.3. Product Version: 2.0.50212.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

Following this I then tried to use the click once application.  This then gave the error:

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Version 1.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of anything that would throw this type of error/prevent the setup from completing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment in the discussion section of this post:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-create-manage/

> [The] documentation needs to be updated to reflect additional software requirements:
> * Windows Management Framework 3+ (or else the installer silently rollsback)
> * .NET 4.5+ (or else the configuration wizard returns a SecurityException)

My guess is that this is the cause of the "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure" error.

There appears to be some debate about how to definitively determine the WMF version currently installed, but the top answer on this question seems to be the popular choice:
https://serverfault.com/questions/627386/what-version-of-windows-management-framework-is-installed

Look for a WSManStackVersion value greater than 3.0.

If it is less then you need to install WMF 3.0 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) at least (the current version is 5.0). Be sure to review the System Requirements to make sure the machine you are installing on won't conflict with them.

If the machine meets those requirements, try running the msiexec in verbose mode and send the output to a file to get a log of the install process:

msiexec /i _path_to_msi_ /L*V _path_to_output_file

It might give you a new direction to look.